# HP ProCurve 2910al dual personality ports media type

Tags: hp, switch

I got my hands on a few HP ProCurve 2910al switches and they have 4 dual-personality ports (either rj45 or SPF module), and I need to force the switch to use rj45.

The rj45 ports were working before, but then I tried some SFP transceivers. They were not compatible, but ever since, the rj45 ports are disabled, even after removing the SFP modules. I tried enabling/disabling the ports with `enable`/`disable` commands and rebooting the whole switch, but nothing. One of the switches eventually after few hours of runtime switched back to rj45, got link and is now working, but I have 3 more, which are refusing to use that ports.

I'm more of a Cisco guy and I know there is command `media-type (rj45|sfp|auto)` on Cisco swithes, but I was unable to find HP equivalent. I will have to use these switche for a while in a production, and I don't want any surprises, so I would like to force them into using rj45.

How to do that?
Thanks.